# React Route not redirecting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have the below routes in my code.

On the below route, by selecting create contact it redirects to route2. If I click again on route 1 option from the side menu I am not getting redirected the route 1 page, once the URL changes I still remain in the create page. Could someone help me on this?

**route 1 :** /dashboard/settings/templates

**route 2 :** /dashboard/settings/templates/contact/create

```
<Route
   exact
   path="/dashboard/settings/templates"
   render={(props) => <Templates {...props} />}
/>

<Route
   exact
   path="/dashboard/settings/templates/:role/:template"
   render={(props) => <Templates mode="edit" {...props} />}
/>
```

Thank you,
Promod S

Comment: It's difficult to help you without seeing your code. How are your routes defined? Are you using Switch? You might need to declare the second route before the first one.

Comment: most likely you missed out adding ```exact``` prop to ```Link ```

Comment: Could you share a piece of code where you declare and use the routes?

Comment: @IsmaelPadilla They both are under the same switch

Comment: @RohitPrasad have already added it bro, still no luck

Comment: Other than within a `Switch` you *should* define *more* specific routes before *less* specific routes (fixed by instead specifying the `exact` prop on each) we need to also see the navigation code. How are your links defined. Can you provide a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue?

Comment: did you wrap the `<App/>` component with browser router?